# PHP - How to replace a phrase with another?

Tags: php, html, string

How can i replace this `<p><span class="headline">`  with this `<p class="headline"><span>`
easiest  with PHP.

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs1.html");
$clean1 = strstr($data, '<p>');
$str = preg_replace('#(<a.*>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $clean1);
$ausgabe = strip_tags($str, '<p>');
echo $ausgabe;
```

Before I alter the html from the site I want to get the class declaration from the span to  the  `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)?

If the placement of the `<p>` and `<span>` tags are consistent, you can simply replace one for the other with

```
str_replace("replacement", "part to replace", $string);
```

Comment: thx  for  your very  fast help  like  all the others!   this worked  fine for me

Answer (score 3):

dont parse html with regex!
this class should provide what you need
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: that  looks  very  nice i  will  investigate it further

Answer (score 1):

The reason not to parse HTML with regex is **if you can't guarantee the format**.  If you already know the format of the string, you don't have to worry about having a complete parser.

In your case, if you know that's the format, you can use `str_replace`

`str_replace('<p><span class="headline">', '<p class="headline"><span>', $data);`

Comment: the html  in my  case  always  has  the same  format. but  thx   for your  answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, answer was accepted already, but anyway, here is how to do it with native DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.ihr-apotheker.de/cs1.html");
$xPath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// remove links but keep link text
foreach($xPath->query('//a') as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $dom->createTextNode($link->nodeValue), $link);
}

// switch classes    
foreach($xPath->query('//p/span[@class="headline"]') as $node) {
    $node->removeAttribute('class');
    $node->parentNode->setAttribute('class', 'headline');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

On a sidenote, HTML has elements for headings, so why not use a `<h*>` element instead of using the semantically superfluous "headline" class.

Comment: because  i like  to  edit  css  files more  then  to code  in the  html - additionally  i  want  to look  them different  then the rest  of my  headlines

Comment: if  i want  to  erase  the  text  of  the link  also  i  just  leave  the line  with   $dom->createTextNode($link->nodeValue), $link);
i guess?

Comment: @Arwed You have to distinguish between semantic structure and presentation. The `<h*>` elements structure your code, but they dont say how the headings will look. The fact that browsers usually render them big and bold is a browser thing. A text-browser wouldnt do this. Also, you can still style the same `<h*>` by applying different classes.

Comment: @Arwed If you want to erase the text of the link as well, you are effectively erasing the entire link. In this case use `$link->parentNode->removeChild($link)`. When working with XML you have to understand the node concept. <a href="#">foo</a> is three nodes. An element node for `a`, an attribute for `a`'s `href` and a child text node for `foo`.