# How to replace a node with a string using DOMDocument

Tags: php, replace, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - How to replace a phrase with another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388836/php-how-to-replace-a-phrase-with-another)

I need to transform this piece of html

```
<html>
   <body>
      Lorum ipsum <a href="http://google.com">click here</a> dolores lorem.
      Lorum ipsum <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click here too</a> dolores lorem.
   </body>
</html>
```

To:

```
<html>
    <body>
       Lorum ipsum @@1@@ dolores lorem.
       Lorum ipsum @@2@@ dolores lorem.
    </body>
</html>
```

How can this be achieved using Domdocument (I'm not interested in een regex solution)?

Comment: replace the DOMElement of all As with DOMText Nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not shown any code so far so it is not really clear into which problem you run. I can only assume that it is because if you iterate over the list of links changing it, the iteration will get invalid. So only the first element is being replaced.

Using a `for` loop can help here only getting the first a element per each iteration. It would also allow to initialize and increase the count variable for the numbers you need in the replacement.

The replacement itself can be easily done with [`replaceChild`](http://php.net/domnode.replacechild). The loop example:

```
for($c = 1; $a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0); $c++) {
    $a->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $doc->createTextNode(sprintf("@@%d@@", $c)),
        $a
    );
}
```

The call to `$doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)` will return `NULL` if no such element exists (any longer). That is the exit condition of the loop.

Full example:

```
$html = '<html><body>
  Lorum ipsum <a href="http://google.com">click here</a> dolores lorem.
  Lorum ipsum <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click here too</a> dolores lorem.
</body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);

for($c = 1; $a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0); $c++) {
    $a->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $doc->createTextNode(sprintf("@@%d@@", $c)),
        $a
    );
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
  Lorum ipsum @@1@@ dolores lorem.
  Lorum ipsum @@2@@ dolores lorem.
</body></html>
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't `$doc->getElementsByTagName('a')` on each iteration be a performance issue?

Comment: @jackflash: No, it's working perfectly fast. I would even assume it's working faster then keeping the list of elements to be deleted later. I once did it that way in some answer which works, too, but I would not worry at all about performance here. Don't guess with performance issues, metric so you know if there is a *real* issue. Unless you don't do that, do not care about it. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @jackflash: Just seeing that with xpath results it works probably more straight forward, in case you're interested. I edited the existing answer to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389140/367456